# UIActivityViewController not sharing animated GIF to Twitter

Tags: ios, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am unable to share an animated GIF via the UIActivityViewController and the Twitter app.  The result I get is a static image, the first frame of the animation.

Using the same UIActivityViewController, I am able to share the animated GIF via Slack, Facebook Messenger, and the Messages app.  Twitter seems to be the exception.

The GIF is stored as an NSData object.  I am initializing the activity controller and passing the object to it.  The image is about 700kb total - well beneath the 5mb cap on mobile.

This was done using an iPhone X, using iOS 12.2

```
[self.view animatedGif:^(NSData *gifData) {
    // make sure we perform UI changes on the main thread via GCD
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIActivityViewController *avc  = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
                                                  initWithActivityItems:@[gifData]
                                                  applicationActivities:nil]; 

        [self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}];
```

Twitter only displays the result as a single image - the first frame of the animation.  How can I get it to send and display the entire animation?